# Migrate byte array files in sql database to files in file system

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

we have an old database that contain files as byte array in a table, & we want to migrate the whole data to a new database with different structure using a migration script,
but the problem is that in the new database there is no equivalent table for that old files table & those files must be saved in file system.
so the question is, does T-SQL has a way to convert byte array data to files & save them in file system?

Comment: Maybe you should think of using a small program or script to do this task?

Comment: Yes, it seems easy to develop a small console app to do this task for me. I'll go for it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some ways to do it
you can read it

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/exporting-data-programatically-with-bcp-and-xp_cmdshell

and use things like it

```
DECLARE @wk_no VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @Path VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @MD VARCHAR(100)

SET @wk_no = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE())
SET @Path = 'D:\FolderName\'

SET @MD = ' mkdir ' + @Path + 'WK' + @wk_no
```

...Replace ' mkdir ' with create file name script or syntax...

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell @MD, no_output
PRINT @MD
```

But Nils is right. Why not write a small program to do it in you preferred language? It ill be faster, easier to keep and maintain and less I/O errors prone.